# swagger codegen keyword additions

Tags: java, json, swagger

I have to maintain a project that uses Swagger to codegen the api interface.  Looking at the model.mustache, I see this:

```
{{#models}}                  
{{#model}}{{#description}}   
/**                          
 * {{description}}           
 **/{{/description}}
```

and a bunch of other keywords like enum, defaultValue, vars, package, etc.  Where do these come from?  I've been scouring the internet trying to find swagger documentation on this but I cannot find anything.  Lots of the links that refer to swagger info on github return 404 pages.  In the end, what I want to be able to do is to have a property exist in my actual .json file that swagger is using to generate the interfaces and models to conditionally generate code.  I saw that there is the

```
{{#property}}{{/property}}
{{^property}}{{/property}}
```

notation for if/else statements, but it doesn’t work on any property of my own .json.  For example, in my json I have an id field.  So if I wanted to do a contrived example

```
{{#id}}System.out.println(“test test”);{{/id}}
```

won’t work because swagger does not recognize the id tag.  So my question is, can I add these tags?

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of tools to help out.  If you see broken links, please submit issues to the [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) project.

As of 2.1.x-M1, swagger-codegen has a very helpful "debug" mode which lets you list all the possible values for your environment.  You can invoke it as follows:

```
java -DdebugModels -jar {path-to}/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate {opts}
```

The supported debug flags are:

```
-DdebugModels: outputs the variables for each model discovered by codegen
-DdebugOperations: outputs the variables for each operation
-DdebugSupportingFiles: shows supporting file data (anything but models or operations)
-DdebugSwagger: shows the parsed swagger representation
```

I do see that these are missing from the README.  Will make sure they get added.